# Relationship between a basis and its dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Does every basis $\gamma=\{\text{f}_1,\cdots,\text{f}_n\}\in V^*$ correspond to a unique collection $\beta\subset V$ such that (1) $\beta$ is a basis for $V$, and (2) $\gamma$ is the dual basis of $\beta$? Worded slightly differently, if we show that a collection $\beta=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\subset V$ satisfies $\text{f}_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$, are we guaranteed that $\beta$ is the unique basis such that $\gamma$ is its dual basis? Is there a bijection between the collection of bases of $V$ and the collection of bases of $V^*$ where bases are matched with their dual bases?

The corollary to Theorem 2.26 in Friedberg, Insel & Spence's fifth edition of "Linear Algebra" says that every ordered basis for $V^*$ is the dual basis for some basis for $V$, and I am unsure about the exact relationships that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you said is correct, but the fact that the dimension of $V$ is finite is crucial, for it says that the map $$V \ni v \mapsto (f \mapsto f(v))\in V^{**}$$is an isomorphism.

If $B$ is a basis for $V$, one constructs the associated dual basis $B^*$. Repeating this process with $V^*$ and $B^*$ playing the roles of $V$ and $B$ gives us the dual basis $B^{**}$ of $B^*$, in $V^{**}$. Hit this basis $B^{**}$ with the isomorphism $V^{**}\to V$. You get, wait for it... that's right, $B$.

So there is a "natural" (in a very precise categorical meaning) correspondence between bases for $V$ and bases for $V^*$.

Comment: This interpretation of the isomorphism is very helpful. I think I now see why for any basis $\gamma\subset V^*$ there is exactly one basis $\beta\subset V$ such that $\gamma$ is its dual basis, having to do with the image of that dual basis in the double dual under the isomorphism. I think the one thing I still do not understand is how we are assured that a collection $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}\subset V$ which satisfies $\text{f}_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$ IS $\beta$ -- it seems like a necessary but not sufficient condition. For example, it's conceivable to me that the collection could be linearly dependent

Comment: It's linearly independent. Write $$a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n=0,$$and apply $f_i$ on both sides to get $a_i=0$.

Comment: Also: if $f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and $f_i(w_j)=\delta_{ij}$, then $v_1=w_1$, ..., $v_n=w_n$. Once this is in place, it will follow that $B$ equals the image of $B^{**}$ under $V^{**}\to V$, because both are related to $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ by the same way. How to prove it? It suffices to show that $v_1=w_1$ since the same argument works for the rest. Since $B^*$ spans $V^*$, we have that $f(v_1)=f(w_1)$ for all $f\in V^*$. This says that the images of $v_1$ and $w_1$ under $V\to V^{**}$ are equal, but this map is injective. So $v_1=w_1$.

Comment: Is the reason $f(v_j)=f(w_j)$ for all $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ because $f(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(v_i)f_i(v_j)=f(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(w_i)f_i(v_j)$? If so, I think my confusion has been assuaged. Thanks!

Comment: Every element of $V^*$ is a linear combination of the elements of $V^* and evaluation is a linear procedure.